# How to track the ethereum beta site's performance?

Tags: discussion, questions, recent-activity, statistics

Is there any way for non-moderators to track the ethereum beta site's performance?

For instance the questions per day moving average of the last 14 days? I [read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/226837) 10 questions a day make up a healthy beta.

> When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the following query on data stack exchange, make sure to select ethereum:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CreationDate, 101) AS [day], COUNT(*) as [count]
FROM Posts

 -- query questions only --
WHERE PostTypeId = 1

 -- cut off private beta --
AND CONVERT(DATE, CreationDate, 101) > '2016-02-01 00:00:00'

GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, CreationDate, 101)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, CreationDate, 101)
```

[Direct link to results](https://data.stackexchange.com/ethereum/query/478426/questions-per-day-on-stack-exchange#resultSets).

[image: screenshot of the graph]

[Direct link to graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/ethereum/query/478426/questions-per-day-on-stack-exchange#graph).